# Ver si parte de una lista pertenece a otra

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo dos listas llamadas playerCards con 3 strings y muestraCards con 5 strings. Lo que yo quiero ver es que si por lo menos 2 strings de playerCards pertenecen a muestraCards hacer Flor = true

```
Flor = false;
var muestraCards = new List<string>() { "M2", "M4", "M5", "MJ", "MQ" };
var playerCards = new List<string>() { "E4", "MJ", "M2" };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [Intersect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-8.0)

```
    var interseccion = muestraCards.Intersect(playerCards);

    if (interseccion.Count() >= 2)
    {
        //* 2 strings de playerCards pertenecen a muestraCards.
        Flor = true
    }
```

Este sería un ejemplo completo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ExampleIntersect
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         bool Flor = false;
        var muestraCards = new List<string>() { "M2", "M4", "M5", "MJ", "MQ" };
var playerCards = new List<string>() { "E4", "MJ", "M2" };

        var interseccion = muestraCards.Intersect(playerCards);
        if (interseccion.Count() >= 2)
        {
            Flor = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("valor de Flor: " + Flor);
    }
}
```